# SSRS range chart with repeating series

Tags: charts, reporting-services-2012

I am plotting a range chart in `SSRS 2012` containing the stages an order moves through before completion. The Order is the category group, the stage is the series group and I have a start and end date for each stage set as the high/low values.

The chart should look something like the below:

```
|
|| Initial Phase | Secondary Phase | Tertiary Phase | Completion |
|
```

The issue I am having is once an order has moved beyond a stage, it may return to the stage previous as in below:

```
|
|| Initial Phase | Secondary Phase | Tertiary Phase |  Secondary Phase | etc...
|
```

The repeated stage is not being plotted on the chart, resulting in an area of blank space.

I have tested that it is repeating series causing the issue by numbering each series (i.e. secondary series 1, secondary series 2 etc.) and the chart renders as desired.

There are too many stages and too many movements to display each time an order moves to a new phase as a new series. Can anyone provide anything to get me thinking on the right track to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the issue, but came up with a workaround.

I stuck with the following with a numeral postfix:

```
     |  
     || Initial Phase1 | Secondary Phase1 | Tertiary Phase1 |  Secondary Phase2 | 
     |
```

I grouped the series on the numeral postfixes, but used a colour expression to colour based on the phase name without the numeral postfix:

```
     |  colour:Red       colour:Blue         colour:Green      colour:Blue
     || Initial Phase | Secondary Phase | Tertiary Phase |  Secondary Phase | 
     |
```

I then created my own 'legend' using a table, grouping on the the phase name without the numeral postfix and showing the phase colour in a cell